# Tell Tramp not to try again if login fails

Tags: tramp

We have this policy that the account gets locked if a user tries to login with the wrong password for three times.

Now if I mistype my password when connecting via tramp, it will try to login several times, locking my account immediately.

I could not find a way to disable multiple login attempts. Is there a way to tell tramp to try only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tramp should automatically recognise a wrong password error and prompt you for a new password.  If it doesn't, it probably indicates that the remote host is using a weird string to report password errors.

Please set the variable `tramp-verbose` to `6`, then check the `*debug tramp/whatever*` buffer to find out what error message the host is checking.  Then customise the variable `tramp-wrong-password-reject` to match it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing `C-g` right after the first login attempt fails.

Then clean the connection with `M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection` before trying to login again.

Comment: It's way faster than my reaction time...

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean it is not working for you?

Comment: It does a series of futile login attempts within about second, no way to notice and press some keys in that time frame at least for me.